# Modeling a database many to many relationship between three tables using sqlalchemy in python

Tags: python, database-design, model, sqlalchemy, relationship

Let's consider the following table models for sqlalchemy in python.

```
class Worker(Base):
    id Column(Integer, primary = True)
    name Column(String, nullable = False)

class Project(Base):
    id Column(Integer, primary = True)
    name Column(String, nullable = False)

class Rating(Base):
    id Column(Integer, primary = True)
    description Column(String, nullable = False)
```

Let's consider some restrictions on these tables. (Don't question the sense of this example please, it is the best I came up with to describe what I'd like to learn. :-))

1. A `worker` may have multiple `projects` to work on.
2. A `project` may have multiple `workers` assigned to work on it.
3. For each tuple `(worker, project)` you have a distinct `rating`

I understand, that I have three many to many relationship. Those are:

1. worker and project
2. worker and rating
3. rating and project

I have no problems defining a many to many relationship between two tables. I just would have to add the folowing association table and a realtionship to my models.

```
worker_project = Table('worker_project', METADATA,
                       Column('worker_id', Integer, ForeignKey('workers.id')),
                       Column('project_id', Integer, ForeignKey('projects.id')),

class Worker(Base):
    # [...]
    papers = relationship('Project',
                          secondary=worker_project,
                          backref='workers')
```

**What I do fail in, is to link the table "ratings" like described above.** Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make the ratings table something like this.

```
  Rating
---------------------
  rating_id (primary key) 
  worker_id (foreign key - worker(worker_id)) 
  project_id (foreign key - project(project_id)) 
  description
```

If I'm understanding this correctly that is.

Comment: Assuming some data in the database, this would mean: `worker.rating_id` would give me a set of all the ratings for a worker. `project.rating_id` would give me a set of all the ratings of all the workers working on the particular project. Right? Given a worker and a project I would have always to calculate the intersection of `worker.rating_id` and `project.rating_id` to get the rating of the given author at a certain project, right?

Comment: If you have a workerid and a projectid, you would just "SELECT * FROM Rating WHERE workerid = ? AND projectid = ?;" and would give you the rating row for that 'project + worker' combo (don't know how to translate that to sqlalchemy syntax).  I don't think you need many-many relations between worker and rating.

Comment: I'm assuming you want only want one rating for each (project+worker) btw.

Comment: That's exactly what I wanted to know, thank you very much! I will try this and see how it turns out.